# With Core 2.1 and Razor pages, how can I scaffold a model and NOT use the ID field

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Scaffold creates code like this 
    Edit
Which yields url's like this 
    '.../Students/Edit?id=2'
or 
    '.../Students/Edit/2'
Something like 
    '.../Student/Edit/0hBMeEjw5Wqm'

I am creating a field for each record that contains the database (int) ID hashed with a salt and set to twelve characters.  I would prefer to display that value rather than consecutive numbers, not trying 'security through obscurity'; just don't want to display consecutive numbers.

Comment: What is the name of the property with your hashed value? You need to define a route using that rather that the default `{controller}/{action}/{id}` (i.e. replace `{id}` with `{yourPropertyName}`

Comment: @StephenMuecke; PERFECT!  I apologize for asking such an easy question.  Thank you for being so polite.